# Download script for PHP

Tags: php, html

In my website I want the users to download a music file when a button is clicked. The problem I am experiencing is that when the button is clicked the download starts but only 506 KB on a total of 4 MB are downloaded and when it is opened it shows unsupported format. I use this php download script with html form to make the download:

HTML FORM

```
<FORM ACTION="download.php" METHOD=POST>
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="music"    VALUE= "music/<? print $file; ?>"  >
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="download"  VALUE="Download">
</FORM>
```

PHP DOWNLOAD SCRIPT

```
<?php
$FileName = $_POST["music"];
$FilePath = "music";
$size = filesize($FilePath . $FileName);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"". $FileName ."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". $size ."");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $FileName ."\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Pragma: private");
echo (readfile($FilePath . $FileName));
?>
```

Can you please point me to the problem?

Comment: Look in the downloaded file and see whether there are any errors.

Comment: If you format code with 4 spaces instead of the `\``, you won't get the white lines in between, it's a bit easier to read ;)  (or you select the code, and use the `{}` button.

Comment: yes the file is not playing.....kk will do next time :)

Comment: Currently, one can download *any* file. You should absolutely validate the input.

Comment: change your memory limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for a file in a location like:

```
musicmusic/file.mp3
```

Assuming your file is actually stored in something like `music/file.mp3`, and variable `$file` contains something like `file.mp3`, you want to replace:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="music" VALUE= "music/<? print $file; ?>">
```

with:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="music" VALUE= "<? print $file; ?>">
```

and then replace this:

```
$FilePath = "music";
```

with:

```
$FilePath = "music/";
```

*(or delete `$FilePath` at all)*

Also, I would recommend you to check `$_POST["music"]` doesn't contain `..` or start with `/` before you let anyone download any file from your server.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a binary editor to check whether there is no PHP error message *(or try downloading a `.txt` file and check its content)*?

Comment: thanks man it worked :)....i took your advice changed in every script and it worked thanks man...:)